# Shared MutableLiveData gets null in a different fragment

Tags: android

So, i have my viewModel in which holds a city2 varaible which is of type mutablelivedata, and im trying to use Transformations in order to fetch data only when the city name has changed.
i have my homescreen fragment, in which im simply getting the city name of what the user has entered, and navigating to the second fragment using findNavController and im passing a bundle with the city name.
I have my second fragment in which gets that city and fetches the weather using that city name, im setting the value of the city MutableLiveData and it updates to the one passed from the home fragment.

i have my favorite fragment in which im able to press on a specific city and i'm passing that city name to the second fragment again.
for some reason the value of city2 is null at that point and it fetches the weather for that city once again.
Why the value becomes null at that point? if i set the value of it when navigating from the first fragment to the second fragment since the first place.

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
    class WeatherScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository,
        private val geoCoderRepository: GeoCoderRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

        private val _weather = MutableLiveData<Resource<AllDataNew>>()

        val weather : LiveData<Resource<AllDataNew>> get() = _weather


        //val city = MutableLiveData<String>()


        val favourites :LiveData<List<Favourites>> = weatherRepository.getAllFavourites()


        //using transformation to fetch data only if the city variable is changed
        //in that way we obtain the chance to fetch data only of the data of the weather has changed and not in everytime we are gonna get to that screen
        val city2 = MutableLiveData<String>()
        val transformationWeather = city2.switchMap { cityName ->
            liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
                val geoResult = geoCoderRepository.cityToLongLat(cityName)
                if (geoResult.status is Success) {
                    val list = listOf(
                        geoResult.status.data!!.lat,
                        geoResult.status.data!!.long!!
                    )
                    val notNullList: List<Double> = list.filterNotNull()
                    emit(weatherRepository.fetchWeather(notNullList))
                }
            }
        }

        fun setCity(cityInput:String){
            Log.d("city_input_get_string",cityInput)
            city2.value = cityInput
        }
}
```

**First Fragment**

```
private val viewModel : WeatherScreenViewModel by viewModels()
binding.btnShowCity.setOnClickListener {
            if(!city.isNullOrEmpty()){
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeScreenFragment_to_weatherScreenFragment, bundleOf("city" to city))
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Enter city name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

**Second fragment**

```
private val viewModel : WeatherScreenViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.getString("city")?.let {
            city = it
            //using transformation
            viewModel.setCity(it)
            Log.d("first_get_string",viewModel.city2.value!!)
            
        }

        arguments?.getString("fav_city")?.let {
            //using transformation
            Log.d("fav_city_get_string",it)
            viewModel.city2.value?.let { it1 -> Log.d("second_get_string", it1) }
            viewModel.setCity(it)




            city = it
           
        }
```

**in that line of code the  viewModel.city2.value is null i dont get it **
arguments?.getString("fav_city")?.let

**Third Fragment**

```
private val viewModel : WeatherScreenViewModel by viewModels()
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.favourites.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            binding.favouritesRv.adapter = FavouritesAdapter(it,object : FavouritesAdapter.FavouriteListener{
                override fun onFavouriteClick(city: String) {
                    //Toast.makeText(requireContext(),city,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_favouritesFragment_to_weatherScreenFragment,bundleOf("fav_city" to city))
                }
            },requireContext())

            binding.favouritesRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        }
```

Thanks for everyone!

Im not sure but i was thinking to make another viewHolder only for that city variable which will hold the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
I figured it out, the issue was that each fragment created his own instance of the viewModel
instead of using private val viewModel : WeatherScreenViewModel by activityViewModels()

i used by viewModels() in both, and that what caused to the problem.